# Unable to run babel via npm script "babel: command not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

To get started I ran:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Here is my package.json:

```
   {
      "scripts": {
        "build": "babel src -d dist"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.6.5",
        "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0"
      }
    }
```

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

My file structure is like this:

```
- Root
    - src
        - client 
        - server
        - test  
    - dist 
    - package.json
```

I am calling npm run build from the root folder. I am expecting it to compile the source folder into the dist folder. It runs and then I get this error:

```
> babel src -d dist

sh: babel: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! redacted@1.0.0 build: `babel src -d dist`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redacted@1.0.0 build script 'babel src -d dist'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the redacted package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel src -d dist
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs redacted
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls redacted
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/redacted/npm-debug.log
```

So as you can see, I've installed babel-cli, I've installed the presets, and I think everything is in order according to the babel docs.

Does anyone have ideas about why it wouldn't be working? Could I be missing a babel npm file? Is "babel src -d dist" incorrect?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

I made another folder and followed the same steps, it worked perfectly. For some reason it's not working in this directory.

Comment: Have you done 'npm i'? Can you see them in node_modules?

Comment: @geraint yes I have! For each one I did npm install and used --save-dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you run "npm install" to install the dev packages?

Comment: yes I have! For each one I did npm install and used --save-dev

Comment: Could you list the node_modules folder? And the ./node_modules/.bin?  ls -l node_modules and ls -l ./node_modules/.bin

Comment: Yep, it's a pretty large list so I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WVkWnixf @s.xie

Comment: Looks like you don't have a babel lnk file under ./node_module/.bin/
babel -> ../babel-cli/bin/babel.js*

Comment: You can either create the symbol link:
ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js

or remove node_modules folder and run npm install command again.

Comment: Removing node modules folder an reinstalling everything worked.. though I'm not sure why? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling doesn't work, check what version of node you're using `node --version` if it's <= v2 then upgrade node and try again. Hint: Babel takes a long time to install on node v2 for some reason.

Answer (score 18):

I've come across the same issue lately. Removing the node_modules folder and running `npm install` again no longer fixes the issue.

The reason you are getting this error is because babel-cli needs to be installed globally, not as a project dependency.

Run `npm install -g babel-cli` to install it globally.

Babel-preset-es2015 can then be installed as a dev dependency for your projects `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: This will get the command working, the only caveat is that the [Babel CLI docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) strongly recommend that you don't install globally, even going so far as to suggest running `npm uninstall --global babel-cli` if you do have it installed globally. In their words this is because:
_**1.** Different projects on the same machine can depend on different versions of Babel allowing you to update one at a time.
**2.** It means you do not have an implicit dependency on the environment you are working in. Making your project far more portable and easier to setup._

Comment: It isn't a good practice to use a global installation of `babel-cli`, besides removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` **still** fixes the issue

Answer (score 14):

You should never install babel-cli globally - in fact, they [specifically have an entire paragraph telling you not to](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) from their official docs.

Edit `package.json` >> add a script with the key called, say, `build` with the value `./node_modules/.bin/babel <commands>`

If you called it `build`, just then type `npm run build`.

Answer (score 10):

The error occurs because `./node_modules/.bin` is not in `$PATH`. `./node_modules/.bin` is where all the executable binaries can be found.

As recommended by the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli), you can reference the `babel` cli inside of `node_modules`:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib
```

You can modify your `npm run build` command to use this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist"
},
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be in $PATH when running command "npm run build" which is using the local copy.

Comment: I tried this and I actually still receive the exact same error. I looked inside the bin folder and there is nothing in there with the name "babel"

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers above are correct.

> The error occurs because ./node_modules/.bin is not in `$PATH`. `./node_modules/.bin` is where all the executable binaries can be found.

What I did was I built a simple dynamic alias function in my zshrc file.

```
# Babel
function bbl() {
    ./node_modules/.bin/babel "$@"
}
```

Now you can use `bbl` instead of babel

```
bbl --version
6.24.1 (babel-core 6.25.0)
```